# Having Trouble With The Reversal of a String

Tags: c++

```
class Solution {
public:
    string reverseWords(string s) {
     int previousWhiteSpace = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i <= s.size(); i ++){
         if(isspace(s[i]) || i == s.size()){
            for(int j = previousWhiteSpace; j < i/2; j++){
            char temp = s[j];
            s[j] = s[i-1-j];
            s[i-1-j] = temp;
            }
         previousWhiteSpace = i + 1;
         }
     }
    return s;
    }
};
```

Hi. So the goal of my function is to reverse the input of a string. So for example, if I am given "Let's take LeetCode contest" , my function should return  "s'teL ekat edoCteeL tsetnoc" . However, currently my function is ONLY returning 
"s'teL take LeetCode contest" . I have a counter which I indicate as previousWhiteSpace to keep track of the start of every new word that seems to work for the first word, but not the rest. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you step through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Hi, so I stepped through the debugger and found out that my for loop is being skipped entirely for some reason. At the same time, my variable for j is being set to a number that is not equal to previousWhiteSpace. My variable j on the second go around, after finding the second whitespace, is being set to 2 rather than the value of 6 which is where the word take begins. After landing on the line for the for loop, the program entirely skips the exchange within the middle and immediately goes to the setter line for previousWhiteSpace.

Comment: Anyone curious as to why my for loop is being skipped, it is because of i/2. When I get to the word take, my variable i is set to 10 which when it is divided by 2 is equal to 5. If you take this idea and extend it over to all the other words, it would be less than the value of the variable j hence the for loop being skipped. To go around it, I thought of doing (i - (i-previousWhiteSpace)/2) and am currently stuck on debugging that! Thanks guys.

Comment: If anyone would like the see the solution to this problem, I have it posted here: https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-words-in-a-string-iii/discuss/142654/2ms-C%2B%2B-Code/149156

Answer (score -1):

You can simply assign **" "** to the variable **previousWhiteSpace** and no need to increment. thus your code will detect **white space** automatically till the end of the string and will run the code after every **white space**. As you have assigned value 0 to it will only perform the result for the first word and it will terminate.

Comment: Hi Rajdeep! How I understood your answer was that in my conditional statement I replace isspace(s[i]) to be s[i] == " ", if I am not mistaken. Also I have uploaded a version of the code that runs correctly on LeetCode, the link to which you can find above! Thank you for the help!